# A new shorter URL for a Host-named site collection?

Tags: 2010, url, host-header

I have a SharePoint 2010 environment that has a Web Application which has 15 site collections.

One of the site collection is a Host-named site collection, and its URL is: (http://Sales.Corp.com/).

The site owner and the end-user requested that if they type "Sales" in their Web browser > The (http://Sales.Corp.com/) site should open for them.

How to accomplish this?

I am confused about different topics: AAMs, Vanity URL, DNS, IIS Manager,...etc. I am NOT sure what is the right and proper way.

I would sincerely appreciate if anyone could help me out on what should I do to achieve the users' request ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot Use the AAM setting for HNSC because AAM for Web App level settings., you cannot use multiple host names to address a site collection in SharePoint 2010. Because host-named site collections have a single URL, they do not support alternate access mappings and a[re always considered to be in the Default zone.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2012/03/27/what-every-sharepoint-admin-needs-to-know-about-host-named-site-collections.aspx)

You can use the 3rd party tools to rewrite the URls(may be works for you).

[Vanity URL allows you to easily create short vanity URLs which point to more complex locations.](http://embraceware.com/vanityurl/en/)

[Use the SharePoint 2010 with IIS URL Rewrite 2.0](http://johnliu.net/blog/2010/7/23/sharepoint-2010-with-iis-url-rewrite-20.html)

http://sharepointshorturl.com/

http://spshorturls.codeplex.com/